# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function enchant_broker_init() - enchant not found?

Tags: centos, php

I have php 5.3.10 (and CentOS 6) and as I understand [enchant](http://php.net/manual/en/book.enchant.php) automatically comes with it. When I try to run an example like

```
$tag = 'en_US';
$r = enchant_broker_init();
$bprovides = enchant_broker_describe($r);
echo "Current broker provides the following backend(s):\n";
print_r($bprovides);
```

I get this php fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function enchant_broker_init()

I can also see this in my php configure command outputted with phpinfo

> -with-enchant=shared,/usr' '--with-recode=shared,/usr'

Do I need to add sg perhaps to php.ini?

Comment: Is glib installed and working? I think there is a dependency in enchant for glib.

Comment: Thanks, glib was not installed. Just did now, but I am still getting this fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like I was naive when I read somewhere that enchant comes packaged with php above 5.3 I still had to

> yum install php-enchant enchant hunspell